# CentOS7(Systemd) で service に target を設定する方法

Tags: centos

#### 前提・実現したいこと

CentOS7 で、CentOS6 での runlevel に当たる設定がしたいです。
service に対する設定方法と確認方法がわかりません。

具体的には、CentOS7 で以下の代替となるコマンドを教えていただきたいです。

```
$ sudo chkconfig --level=2345 mysql on <- runlevel を設定
$ chkconfig --list mysql <- 設定された runlevel を確認
mysqld             0:off    1:off    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

#### 調べたこと

CentOS7では、runlevel ではなく target という概念に変わっていることは
なんとなくわかったのですが、
service に対する設定方法と確認方法がわかりません。

以下コマンドが chconfig --list の代替とされていたのですが、
target の確認ができません。また、target の変更方法もわかりませんでした。

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### runlevel に対応する target の確認

`/lib/systemd/system/runlevel*.target` のリンク先を見ることで概ね理解できるかと思います。

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/runlevel*.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel0.target -> poweroff.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel1.target -> rescue.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel2.target -> multi-user.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel3.target -> multi-user.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel4.target -> multi-user.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target -> graphical.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Feb 15 14:40 /lib/systemd/system/runlevel6.target -> reboot.target
```

#### runlevel(相当)設定変更

ユニット定義ファイル内`[Intall]`セクションの`WantedBy`ディレクティブに記述します。
(以下`yum install mariadb-server`でインストールしたmariadbについて書きますので適宜読み替えてください。)

CentOSオフィシャルパッケージをインストールした場合、ユニット定義ファイルは `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` に置かれます。 ここにある `mariadb.service`ファイルを `/etc/systemd/system/` へコピーし、それを編集します。

デフォルトでは

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

となっているので前節の情報と照らし合わせると`--level=2345`相当であることがわかります。
これを、例えば`--level=5`相当に変更するのであれば、`multi-user.target`を`graphical.target`に書き換えます。

編集が終わったらサービスを有効化します。

```
# systemctl enable mariadb.service
```

#### 設定確認

上記コマンド実行後、対応するディレクトリ `/etc/systemd/system/*.wants/` にシンボリックリンクが置かれますので`ls`で確認できます。

```
$ ls /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/
(前略)
/etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/:
mariadb.service
(後略)
```

正確な意味合いは異なる(WantedByだけが対象ではない)ようですが、ある特定のサービスについて調べたいのであれば`systemctl list-dependencies --reverse`コマンド出力も役に立つかもしれません。

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies --reverse mariadb.service
mariadb.service
● └─graphical.target
```

#### 参考

- [SysVinit to Systemd Cheatsheet - FedoraProject](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet)
- man page: systemd.special(7), systemd.directives(7), systemd.service(5), systemd.unit(5), systemctl(1)